# 'TypeDescriptor' for Methods - Does it exist?

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes

I am wondering if there exists a built in class which provides a functionality similar to that of TypeDescriptor, except for method reflection rather than property.

I require this to dynamically create a context menu based on flagged methods within an object

e.g.

```
    [ContextMenuItem(true)]
    [DisplayName("Do Something")]
    public override void DoSomthing()
    {
        ...
    }
```

I'm starting to build one myself as I haven't found one anywhere, but it always pays to ask :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [DescriptionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.descriptionattribute.aspx) and always look a for a particular string?

```
[Description("SPECIAL")]
void Doit(){}
```

But it's pretty easy to [create your attribute type and then reflect for it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454(VS.71).aspx), this way you can type your own parameters on to it.

Comment: Yea, I'm starting to go down the creating attributes path already (I've already done a lot of them for use with PropertyGrid). However there's no point reinventing the wheel (or at least part of it) if it is around already.